# cannot ping EC2 instance same VPC different CIDR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, cidr

I'm having an issue in the following scenario:

I created a VPC then added the CIDR 192.168.0.0/16 during creation, then I created a public Subnet (192.168.1.0/24) and a private Subnet (192.168.2.0/24), I have EC2 instances running on both subnets.

Then I added a secondary CIDR to my VPC: 11.11.0.0/16, and created a new private Subnet 11.11.1.0/24 and placed a new instance in that subnet.

The issue is that I cannot ping the EC2 instance (with IP 11.11.1.108) from an EC2 instance in the public subnet (192.168.1.198).

I have checked that:

- The new CIDR was included in the VPC's routing table routed as local
- The security group of the 11.11.1.108 EC2 instance has ICMP (all) traffic allowed
- No NACL rules are blocking the traffic
- I can ping other instances in the 192.168.2.0/16

The systems I'm using for the EC2 are Win Server, I presume this is an issue related to NAT as the addresses in the 11.11.0.0/16 are publicly routable (AFAIK), then I'd need to do kind of a translation for it to work but I'm unsure how to do it and why the route for that CIDR was added to VPC's router.

Any help and/or advise is appreciated in advance!

Comment: Windows server firewall typically defaults to blocking ICMP afaik. Can you log in and check? Also, note that 11.11/16 is not a private RFC 1918 prefix but I presume that was deliberate.

Comment: Rather than using ping (which only checks if ping works), what connectivity do you _actually_ want to enable? For example, do you want to allow HTTP or RDP traffic? If so, I'd recommend working on getting them working rather than getting ping working.

Comment: **Side-comment:** The IP address range start with `11` is considered a **public IP address** and might cause problems given that this range of IP addresses actually exists on the Internet. It is better to always use **private IP address ranges** in a VPC. See: [Private network - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

Comment: Hi! thanks to all for the comments, the issue seemed indeed to be the Windows Server 2022 firewall blocking ICMP traffic, for this particular case we require the secondary CIDRs to be non-private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this was the Windows Server 2022 firewall blocking ICMP traffic, but actually the networking works pretty well